# user.priviledge is not able to assigned by array,

Tags: node.js, promise

`user.priviledge` is not able to assigned by array, but other than array its working fine. array I'm using assign to is array of object, when i use only object it working but in array or empty array

```
orgUserController.getAllOrgUser = async () => {
    try {
        let orgUserObj = await OrgUserModelMethod.getAllOrgUsers();
        // console.log(orgUserObj)
        let updatedOrgUser = []

        await Promise.each(orgUserObj, async (user) => {
            user.priviledge = await modulePriviledgeMethod.getModulePriviledge(user._id) // ret array ob object
            updatedOrgUser.push(user)
        })

        return { ...httpStatus.OK, orgUserObj: updatedOrgUser };
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return errorHandler.errorHandlerMain(error);
    }
};
```

Comment: Are you sure `orgUserObj` is iterable?

Comment: yes I printed the value, it array of object

Comment: In that case, it looks like your code is good. In what way is it not working?